MUI: Unsupported linear-gradient with Slider component
When the Material UI slider component is render with a gradient set in the theme, i got an error. Even if the gradient is not used in the slider style.
The theme is set like that :
import { Components, PaletteOptions, Theme, alpha } from '@mui/material';

import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { lighten } from '@mui/material/styles';

const colorPrimaryMain = '#06166B';
const colorPrimaryDark = '#00094D';
const colorPrimaryLight = '#BCC5E3';
const colorTextPrimary = '#ffffff';
const defaultGradient = 'linear-gradient(160deg, #ab0926, #0046c9)';
const defaultGradientHover = `linear-gradient(160deg, ${lighten('#ff0000', .1)}, ${lighten('#0046c9', .1)})`;

const palette: PaletteOptions = {
  primary: {
    main: colorPrimaryMain,
    dark: colorPrimaryDark,
    light: colorPrimaryLight,
  },
  secondary: {
    main: '#FF0000',
    dark: '#D50C21',
  },
  background: {
    default: colorPrimaryMain,
    paper: '#000650',
  },
  text: {
    primary: colorTextPrimary,
  },
  gradient: {
    main: defaultGradient,
    mainHover: defaultGradientHover,
  },
};

export const components: Components = {
  MuiButton: {
    styleOverrides: {
      contained: {
        textDecoration: 'none',
        fontWeight: 500,
        boxShadow: 'none',
        '&:hover': {
          boxShadow: 'none',
        }
      },
      containedSizeSmall: {
        height: 32,
        padding: '0 24px',
        borderRadius: '16px',
        fontSize: 10,
      },
      containedSizeMedium: {
        height: 36,
        padding: '0 24px',
        borderRadius: '18px',
      },
      containedPrimary: {
        // background: defaultGradient,
        background: 'linear-gradient(160deg, #ab0926, #0046c9)',
        '&:hover': {
          background: defaultGradientHover,
        },
        '&.Mui-disabled': {
          background: '#dde1ec',
          color: colorTextPrimary,
        },
      },
      containedSecondary: {
        background: colorPrimaryLight,
      },
    },
  },
  MuiFormControl: {
    defaultProps: {
      margin: 'normal',
    },
    styleOverrides: {
      marginNormal: {
        marginTop: 0,
        marginBottom: '24px',
      },
    },
  },
  MuiInputBase: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        color: colorPrimaryMain,
        fontWeight: 600,
        fontSize: 15,
        '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
          borderColor: alpha(colorPrimaryMain, 0.2),
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
        '&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
          borderColor: alpha(colorPrimaryMain, 0.5),
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
      },
      input: {
        padding: '15px 25px !important',
        borderRadius: '8px',
      },
      inputSizeSmall: {
        padding: '9px 25px !important',
      },
      inputMultiline: {
        height: 'auto !important',
      },
      inputAdornedEnd: {
        paddingRight: '15px !important',
      },
    },
  },
  MuiOutlinedInput: {
    styleOverrides: {
      notchedOutline: {
        borderColor: alpha(colorPrimaryMain, 0.1),
        borderRadius: '8px',
        padding: '0 15px',

        // fix legend background
        legend: {
          fontWeight: 400,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  MuiInputAdornment: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium': {
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  MuiInputLabel: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        transform: 'translate(25px, 15px) scale(1)',
      },
      shrink: {
        transform: 'translate(25px, -9px) scale(.75)',
      },
      asterisk: {
        display: 'none !important',
      },
    },
  },
  MuiMenu: {
    styleOverrides: {
      paper: {
        backgroundColor: `${alpha('#eef2ff', 1)} !important`,
      },
    },
  },
  MuiMenuItem: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        padding: '8px 25px',
        fontWeight: 500,
        color: colorPrimaryMain,
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: alpha(colorPrimaryMain, 0.05),
        },
        '&.Mui-selected': {
          backgroundColor: alpha(colorPrimaryMain, 0.1),
        },
      },
    },
  },
  MuiBackdrop: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        marginTop: '78px',
        background: alpha(colorPrimaryMain, 0.8),
        backdropFilter: 'blur(24.16320037841797px)',
      },
      invisible: {
        background: 'transparent',
        backdropFilter: 'none',
      },
    },
  },
  MuiSwitch: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        padding: 0,
        width: '36px',
        height: '17px',
        marginRight: '0',
        '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
          width: '11px',
          height: '11px',
        },
        '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase': {
          top: '-7px',
          padding: '10px 0px',
          left: '2px',
          color: '#ffffff',
          '&.Mui-checked': {
            color: `${colorPrimaryMain} !important`,
            '&+.MuiSwitch-track':{
              background: 'transparent',
              border: '1px solid',
              borderColor: colorPrimaryMain,
              borderRadius: '36px',
              opacity: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
          background: colorPrimaryMain,
          borderRadius: '36px',
          opacity: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  }
};

export const theme: Theme = createTheme({
  palette,
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
    fontSize: 16,
    htmlFontSize: 16,
    fontWeightBold: 700,
    fontWeightSemiBold: 600,
    fontWeightMedium: 500,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightLight: 300,

    appname: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: '1.25rem',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
    topbar: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontSize: '0.625rem',
      letterSpacing: '.250rem',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
    h1: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontSize: '20px',
    },
    h2: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: '20px',
      letterSpacing: '.100rem',
    },
    h3: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: '16px',
      letterSpacing: '.250rem',
    },
    body1: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
      lineHeight: 1.5,
    },
    body2: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: '0.750rem',
    },
    button: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: '0.9rem',
      letterSpacing: '.100rem',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
    overline: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: '.4375rem',
      letterSpacing: '.100rem',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      lineHeight: '1.5em',
    },
    subtitle2: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: '.5625rem',
    },

    h4: undefined,
    h5: undefined,
    h6: undefined,
    subtitle1: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: '1.25rem',
      letterSpacing: '.100rem',
    },
    caption: {},
  },
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 700,
      sm: 1080,
      md: 1440,
      lg: 1600,
      xl: 1870,
    },
  },
  components,
});

export default theme;

and the with a simple Slider component i got this error:
Uncaught Error: MUI: Unsupported `linear-gradient(160deg, #ab0926, #0046c9)` color.
The following formats are supported: #nnn, #nnnnnn, rgb(), rgba(), hsl(), hsla(), color().

If i remove the gradient from the theme.ts, the component is displayed properly.

Hello, the error is quite explicit. What is your question then?

Sometime, MUI library not supporting gradient colors directly in certain theme things. To overrun this situation we can apply the gradient directly to the Slider component using sx or styleOverrides and remove existing gradient styles from the pallet.
example this may your slider component.
    export const components: Components = {
  MuiSlider: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        '& .MuiSlider-thumb': {
          background: 'linear-gradient(160deg, #ab0926, #0046c9)',
        },
        '& .MuiSlider-track': {
          background: 'linear-gradient(160deg, #ab0926, #0046c9)',
        },
        '& .MuiSlider-rail': {
          background: 'linear-gradient(160deg, #ab0926, #0046c9)',
        },
      },
    },
  },

This is the exact method I used to add gradients along with my theme pallets.
